# ReactComponent cannot be used as a JSX component in spfx tsx webpart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, jsx, spfx

I am making a spfx web part with carousel, for that, I am using react-elastic-carousal [npm-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-elastic-carousel) But when I try to use it, it gives me an error like:

```
Carousel' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its instance type 'ReactElasticCarousel' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'ReactElasticCarousel' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.
```

What I am supposed to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try import Carousel using the following method

```js
import * as Carousel from react-elastic-carousel;
```

Comment: tried it didn't worked :(
Also I tried using react responsive carousel, the same is faced while using it in spfx

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tsconfig.json file inside compilerOptions section:

"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true

As that component has no default export.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering the question, but can you also add an explanation on how this solves the problem?